# Populating TreeView From Object

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a fairly simple class structure where there are `Graphic` objects, each contains a `List<Symbol>` and each `Symbol` contains a `List<Alias>`: amgonst their other properties.

The obvious way (and my current method) is to use nested `foreach` loops to generate the nodes and to populate the tree view (this actually works fine) like below:

```
    public void ToTree(TreeView treeControl)
    {
        treeControl.Nodes.Clear();
        List<TreeNode> graphicsNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (Graphic graphic in Graphics)
        {
            List<TreeNode> symbolNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
            foreach (Symbol symbol in graphic.Symbols)
            {
                List<TreeNode> aliasNodes = new List<TreeNode>();
                foreach (Alias alias in symbol.Aliases)
                {
                    aliasNodes.Add(new TreeNode(alias.AliasName + ": " + alias.AliasValue));
                }
                symbolNodes.Add(new TreeNode(symbol.SymbolName, aliasNodes.ToArray()));
            }
            graphicsNodes.Add(new TreeNode(graphic.FileName, symbolNodes.ToArray()));
        }
        treeControl.Nodes.AddRange(graphicsNodes.ToArray());
    }
```

However, I'm curious if there is anything that I can implement in my class, or any methods that I can overload so that I can simply do something similar to `treeView.Nodes.Add(graphic)`.

Ideally, this would allow for me to determine which object is being clicked on with the `NodeClickEvent` rather than me having to take the node's text and then perform a search separately.

This is so that I would have direct access to the fields and members of each object from within that node, making it much easier to modify properties from the `TreeView` click events.

Comment: That would be possible if you'd create a TreeNodeCollection object.  But pretty unlikely to be a fundamental improvement.  You ought to use Begin/EndUpdate() to avoid excessive painting.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this Beging/EndUpdate() point please?

Comment: @HansPassant strangely enough the TreeNodeCollection doesn't have a public constructor and although it isn't sealed (the one in System.Web is) this makes it close to impossible to extend it  as you can't subclass it or instantiate it. Unless you have a trick up your sleeve ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is create subclasses of [`TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode(v=vs.110).aspx) that accept your classes in their constructor. You can then have each subclass implement the specific handling for that type. I looked into the [suggestion from Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633051/populating-treeview-from-object#comment68498872_40633051) to do something useful with the `TreeNodeCollection` but this class has no public constructor so I couldn't figure out how that should work.

A simple implementation looks like this for your three classes I distilled from your example:

#### Graphic and GraphicNode

```
public class GraphicNode:TreeNode
{ 
    // takes a Graphic instance
    public GraphicNode(Graphic grp)
    {
        // how do you want to represent it
        this.Text = grp.FileName;
        // and this class 'knows' how to handle its children
        Nodes.AddRange(grp.Symbols.Select(s => new SymbolNode(s)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

#### Symbol and SymbolNode

```
public class SymbolNode:TreeNode
{
    public SymbolNode(Symbol sym)
    {
        this.Text = sym.SymbolName;
        Nodes.AddRange(sym.Aliases.Select(ali => new AliasesNode(ali)).ToArray());
    }
}
```

#### Alias and AliasNode

Notice how this class implements a public `Click` method. You can leverage that from an `NodeMouseClick` event.

```
public class AliasesNode:TreeNode
{
    public AliasesNode(Aliases al)
    {
        this.Text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", al.AliasName, al.AliasValue);   
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(new String(this.Text.Reverse().ToArray()));
    }                
}
```

#### Populate the Treeview

The following code populates the Treeview by adding the GraphicNodes. By callimg [`BeginUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beginupdate(v=vs.110).aspx) first, we prevent that the control draws its content on every node that is added. Don't forget to call [`EndUpdate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.endupdate(v=vs.110).aspx) so the control layouts and redraws all newly added nodes. Notice that you only need to add the `GraphicNodes` here, the adding of the other nodes is handled by the subclassed TreeNodes.

```
// tell the control to hold its paint/redraw events until 
// we're done adding all items
tv.BeginUpdate();
foreach(var g in graphics)
{
    tv.Nodes.Add(new GraphicNode(g));
}
// done, draw all nodes now
tv.EndUpdate();
```

If you wire up the NodeMouseClick to the following event handler you can reach into the specific implementation of the TreeNode:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    var node = e.Node as AliasesNode;
    if (node != null)
    {
        node.Click();
    }
}
```

When we click an AliasTreenode we should see the MessageBox popup that is implemented in the `Click` method of that class:

[image: tree view click node]

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. How did you produce that animation btw?